# How can I access Heroku NodeJS server externally?

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I have a websocket server running via NodeJS, and have deployed it to Heroku. There are two separate web applications I wrote that communicate with the websocket server. On localhost, I simply run the node server, load up the applications in a web browser, and all works fine. In Heroku, however, I can't seem to get anything to connect to the url ws://url:port - it just returns an err request timeout.
I don't want to deploy my html using Express per their example. Maybe I could, but this is a test case where some web applications get to be pretty huge.

Is my issue that I have to use wss instead of ws?

Or backing up further, is this a good use case for Heroku or is there something else I should use?

The easiest description of what I'm trying to do: Two websites hosted somewhere that isn't Heroku both communicating with a NodeJS-based websocket server hosted on Heroku.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-websockets?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that explains how to host via express, but I'm trying to avoid doing that for my applications. And to clarify, I have gotten their example working where both the websocket server and static html are hosted on heroku (using ws and express).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I feel pretty dumb because this is about as easy an answer as it gets. For anyone else trying to do the same thing, you don't need to specify the port (Heroku port is for internal use only, and the heroku url you are provided is on port 80). Simply connect using wss (e.g. wss://your-app.herokuapp.com)